# Text Retrieval from EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Why does not

`String.valueOf(edittext var name)`

retrieve the text from `EditText`?

Comment: you should use edittext.getText().toString();  to retrieve text form EditText. If you want to show text inside EditText you should use  edittext.setText("something"); . I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's what Android has provided.

You can just use `editText.getText().toString()` instead.

Info about **`String.valueOf(obj)`**

- `String` class is a Java class, it does not know Android classes like `TextView` or `EditText`.
- `String.valueOf` accept `EditText` or any object because it will be considered to call `String.valueOf(Object)` method.

From **[String Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object))** internal implementation of **`String.valueOf(Object)`** is

```
   public static String valueOf(Object obj) {  
       return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();  
   }
```

If you call `String.valueOf(editText)` It will return you class name like **`EditText@2a139a55`**.

Comment: I know that the code you wrote is working, but what is the reason that the code I wrote is not working?

Comment: Because Android does not provide that method.

Comment: But the thing is that it works for TextView, just a little bit confused because of that

Comment: See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `editTextName.getText().toString()` which returns String value

Comment: The method you are using is used to convert Int value to String value thats the reason its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = String.valueOf(editText.getText())
```